# Application crashes on El Capitan

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, osx-elcapitan

After upgrading to El Capitan, one of our apps has  started crashing because of memory issue as indicated by Address Sanitizer . Crash logs point to genuine issue. This App has been built on Yosemite using XCode and clang. Same app works perfectly fine on Yosemite. So my query is  why this app is not crashing on Yosemite/Mountain Lion? Can we do something in code or OS to disable this kind of crash because of sanitizer.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is unpredictable by nature, so it's not surprising that your app may appear to work on some machines. If you've identified this as a genuine issue, shouldn't you fix it rather than attempt to ignore it?